# 3D point cloud from continuous video stream of two (stereo) cameras

Tags: python, computer-vision, video-processing, point-clouds

I have continuous videos taken from two cameras placed on up right and up left corners of my car's windshield (please note that they are not fixed to each other, and I aligned them approximately straight). Now I am trying to make a 3D point cloud out of that and have no idea how to do that. I surfed the internet a lot and still couldn't find any useful info. Can you send me some links or hints on how can I make that work in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the stereo matching and point cloud generation implementation in the [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) library. Start with this short Python [sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stereo_match.py).

I suppose that you have two independent video streams that are not exactly synchronized. You will have to synchronize them first, because the linked sample expects two images, not videos. Extract images from videos using `OpenCV` or `ffmpeg` and find an image pair that shares exactly the same timepoint (e.g. green appearing on a traffic light). Alternatively you can use the audio tracks for synchronization, see https://github.com/benkno/audio-offset-finder. Beware: synchronization based on a single frame pair or a short audio excerpt will probably work only for few minutes before and after the synchronized timepoint.

Comment: I looked into OpenCV but I thought they only work for one pair of images, is there a way that I can make point cloud from the whole video??

Comment: This has to be done frame by frame anyway, so start with a single frame and then you can process the whole video (if there are no synchronization issues).

Comment: I did what you said, now I have one point cloud (very crappy) for one pair of images

Comment: Have you used synchronized frames - frames from the exactly same time? You can then advance both videos frame by frame from the synchronized point and do the reconstruction for all pairs. Here https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/ you can find out, how to read video frames in OpenCV. Note that you will need two VideoCapture() objects.

Comment: I synced the videos, but I don't see the way to make point clouds from video in the link you sent.

Comment: On the https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/ you can learn how to read a single video. For two videos, you have to open two VideoCapture() objects and in a loop read a single frame from both videos and make a point cloud of of them as you already did. You will end up with lot of point clouds.

Comment: but still I have the following problem. How can I calculate the correct place of the next frame point cloud on the 3 dimensional space, so that software can compose the right PLY file and I can later visualize all frame point clouds in one 3D model as a whole??

Comment: Use Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm to align two point clouds. First you need to compute normals with [cv.ppf_match_3d.computeNormalsPC3d](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d25/group__surface__matching.html#gaa74e62c7b2a8b8a70e44e42211fd00f5) and afterwards you can run ICP ([python sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/surface_matching/samples/ppf_icp.py)). For this to work, you need to have opencv-contrib installed.

Comment: You should also check for radial distortion in images. This could explain the crappy point clouds. For the undistortion you will need to print a chessboard, record a video, find parameters of the distortion and undistort the frames, see https://github.com/smidm/video2calibration (I'm the author).